# Z notation: How to write operation schema that may add one or more tuples to a relation

Tags: formal-languages, formal-methods, z-notation

I'm writing an operation schema in Z. This operation AssignValue maps a property to one or more values.

One property may be linked to one or more values, and one value may be linked to one or more properties, forming a many-to-many relation, R ⊆ Property × Value.

I'm not sure how to write this operation to indicate that one property could be mapped to **one or more values**. I have two versions here. Version A seems to map one property to only one value.

Version A:

```
--AssignValue---
| p? : Property
| v? : Value
-------
|R′ = R ∪ { p? ↦ v? }
-------
```

In Version B, I have added a powerset in the declaration of v? to indicate that v? is a set of values (more than one value).

Version B:

```
--AssignValue---
| p? : Property
| v? : P Value
-------
|R′ = R ∪ { p? ↦ v? }
-------
```

Which version is correct? or there is a better way to represent this? I'm new to z-notation, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown the whole schema.  I assume that you have a state schema `S` with a relation `R : Property<->Value` (equivalent to `R ⊆ Property × Value`) and `AssignValue` includes `∆S`.

Both styles could work, although your version B is probably not what you intended.

A relation is allowed to have many pairs with the same domain element, so starting with

```
R = {p0 ↦ v0, p0 ↦ v1, p3 ↦ v16}
```

You could call `AssignValueA` with `p?=p0`, `v?=v16` to get a state with

```
R = {p0 ↦ v0, p0 ↦ v1, p0 ↦ v16, p3 ↦ v16}
```

that is, `p0` is now mapped to three separate values.

In your version B you have exactly the same thing, but your values are now sets of values.  What you probably intended was that `R` would be a *total function* of type `Property → Value`.  Now, assuming only properties `p0` through `p3`, you would have the initial `R` as

```
R = {p0 ↦ {v0, v1}, p1 ↦ ∅, p2 ↦ ∅, p3 ↦ {v16}}
```

You need to define

```
--AssignValueB----------------
| ∆S
| p? : Property, v? Value
------------
| R' = R ⊕ {p? ↦ R p? ∪ {v?}}
------------------------------
```

This has the same interface as `AssignValueA`, allowing addition of a *single* value to a single property per call.

In both models a property may have no, one or many associated values, but the operation only allows one property to be assigned one extra value per call.

Exercise: try defining an operation that allows multiple properties to be assigned multiple extra values per call.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of a big Z specification, I suggest this recently uploaded project: https://github.com/vinahradau/finma

For a one-to-many, I would use a relation (as an opposite to a function).

Example form the project above:

```
userAccessRigths: USER ↔ ROLE
userAccessRigths′ = userAccessRigths ∪ {(user?, role?)}
```